# Upgrade from Ubuntu 11.04 to 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04

I have an old Ubuntu version 11.04. Version is obsolète. I want to upgrade directly to 13.04 version using my terminal. How can I do it ?

thx in advance
Anis

Comment: You can't. You need to do a full install.

Comment: can I install 13.04 from iso folder extracted to my Ubuntu desktop ?

Comment: Please read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes

Answer (score 1):

as i know you could not skip versions (incompatibility issues), and you must do it step by step

i recommend you to:

update your version to latest using cmd

## sudo aptitude update && aptitude upgrade

and then

## sudo do-release-upgrade -d

and you will upgrade to next version....after that you will do the same, and you will go to the next version

good luck

Comment: leon, it's not working. Apperently It's not possible even to make upgrade version by version. I will make fresh installation. Thanks

Comment: From what I understand, Ubuntu generally uses `apt-get`. Is there a specific reason you recommend `aptitude` over `apt-get`? Do you know if OP has `aptitude` installed? Wouldn't OP have to install `aptitude` first? Shouldn't that be part of your answer? What advantage does going from 11.04 to 11.10 to 12.04 to 12.10 to 13.04 confer over doing a clean install of 13.04 over the existing 11.04 (after backing up essential user data)?